# Graal native image of Spring Boot app fails when scheduling enabled

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

Does a native Spring Boot app support scheduling ?

A very simple Spring Boot app that has these annotations on it fails to start when it's compiled as a native image using graal.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplication {}
```

The error is as follows:

> Invalid declaration of container type
> [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Schedules] for repeatable
> annotation [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled];
> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No value method
> found

Spring Boot 2.4.1, org.springframework.experimental:spring-graalvm-native:0.8.4

Compile script as follows (taken from StarBuxman):

```
native-image \
--verbose \
-H:EnableURLProtocols=http \
-H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows \
-H:Name=$ARTIFACT \
-Dspring.native.verbose=true \
-Dspring.native.remove-jmx-support=true \
-Dspring.native.remove-spel-support=true \
-Dspring.native.remove-yaml-support=true \
-cp $CP $MAINCLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - updating from 0.8.3 to 0.8.4 fixed it.